# Get generic type from an instance

Tags: c#, generics

I have a list that contains objects of type IMyClass.
This list contains instances of typed class MyClass<`T>.
I need to take two random objects from the list of the same MyClass type and perform an operation on them.

My code:

```
var item1 = list[random.Next(list.Count)];
...
var subset = list.OfType<MyClass<item1_T>>().ToList();
var item2 = subset[random.Next(subset.Count)];
```

What do I have to fill in at the dots to get the type item1_T?

Comment: Just get the Type object for item1_T, then construct the type def for MyClass using reflection, and next make the generic method for OfType and invoke it on list, to call ToList on that - all that using duplicates available on Stack Overflow ... 

Comment: @OlivierRogier wouldn't that defeat the purpose of using generics?

Comment: @.MartiendeJong Unless you put all that in a generic method to have item1_T as a generic type parameter at compile-time, you need to use reflexion at runtime to construct all that statement assigning subset, a thing certainly tedious.

Comment: @OlivierRogier How would I approach putting this in a generic method? I think I'm making a design flaw but not sure what it is.

Comment: @.MartiendeJong  In a generic method you can write `... MyMethod<T>(...) { ... var subset = list.OfType<MyClass<T>>().ToList(); ... }`.

Comment: @OlivierRogier when I'm requesting a random item the generic type is irrelevant. Only when finding the other item I need the generic type.

Comment: @OlivierRogier I will see if I can make something with your input. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in C# it is no possible to dynamically specify a generic type using the angle brackets notation as you wrote:

```
var subset = list.OfType<MyClass<item1_T>>().ToList();
```

Although you certainly could call `OfType<>` method using reflection:

```
var list = new List<IMyClass> { ... };

var item1_T = typeof(int);

var subset = (typeof(Enumerable)
    .GetMethod(nameof(Enumerable.OfType))
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(MyClass<>).MakeGenericType(item1_T))
    .Invoke(null, new object[]{ list }) as IEnumerable<IMyClass>)
        .ToList();
```

But that would be quite inefficient.

A much faster way would be:

```
var typeToFind = typeof(MyClass<>).MakeGenericType(item1_T);
var subset = list.Where(item => item != null && item.GetType() == typeToFind).ToList();
```

If this code is not performance critical, probably it wouldn't matter if you use this solution, otherwise I'd suggest to refactor the code to avoid using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

In IMyClass add this line:

```
bool AreInterchangable(IMyClass otherInstance);
```

Implement in MyClass<`T>:

```
public bool AreInterchangable(IMyClass otherInstance)
{
    return otherInstance is IMyClass<T>;
}
```

Instead of var subset = list.OfType<MyClass<item1_T>>().ToList(); use this:

```
var subset = list.Where(item => item.AreInterchangable(item1));
```

Note that I also introduced a generic interface IMyClass<`T> which sits between IMyClass and MyClass<`T>